# 'module' object has no attribute 'Selection' - fields.Selection

Tags: widget, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to code a priority widget, but I keep getting this error: 'module' object has no attribute 'Selection'

My view is defined like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="crm_claim_mod_view">
            <field name="name">crm.claim.mod.view</field>
            <field name="model">crm.claim</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm_claim.crm_case_claims_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                 <field name="priority" position="replace">
                    <field name="priorityNew" widget="priority"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

And I have defined priorityNew as

```
priorityNew = fields.Selection(AVAILABLE_PRIORITIES, 'priorityNew', select=True)
```

where AVAILABLE_PRIORITIES is

```
AVAILABLE_PRIORITIES = [
    ('0', 'Low'),
    ('1', 'Normal'),
    ('2', 'High'),
    ('3', 'Very High'),
    ('4', 'Max'),
]
```

I've tried with fields.selection and fields.Selection, both options give me the *'module' object has no attribute 'Selection'* error (selection or Selection, depending on which one I'm using)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import correctly like

```
from openerp import fields, models, api
```

Also, your XML view will not work - widget priority expects only three values and you have given 5.